# "errorMessage": "local variable 'action' referenced before assignment", "errorType": "UnboundLocalError"

Tags: python

I tried to make the variable action global but it didn't work. It seems that any variable inside the else statement is isolated from the rest of the code, although they are in the same block of code in the for loop.

```
for group in auto_scaling_groups:
    if servers_need_to_be_started(group):
        pass
    else:
        action = "Stopping"
        min_size = 0
        max_size = 0
        desired_capacity = 0

    print("Version is {}".format(botocore.__version__))

    print (action + ": " + group)  #Error in this line 
    response = client.update_auto_scaling_group(
        AutoScalingGroupName=group,
        MinSize=min_size,
        MaxSize=max_size,
        DesiredCapacity=desired_capacity,
    )

    print (response)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `servers_need_to_be_started(group)` is True, var `action` will never be assigned.

Set some default value at start for action.

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying "after executing the "then" block of the if statement, `action` is not set but is used on the error line".  The fix is to ensure `action`, `min_size`, `max_size`, and `desired_capacity` are assigned when the "then" block of the if statement is executed.

Answer (score 2):

The error message pretty much sums it up: your variable `action` is being used (in some cases) before it is defined.

To be more specific, your `action` variable is only defined in your `else` block, meaning that if your condition `servers_need_to_be_started(group)` is true, `action` will never be defined.

So, simply define your variable *outside* of if/else blocks with some default value (e.g. an empty string), and then modify it in your `else` block as needed:

```
for group in auto_scaling_groups:
    action = ""
    if servers_need_to_be_started(group):
        pass
    else:
        action = "Stopping"
        min_size = 0
        max_size = 0
        desired_capacity = 0

    print("Version is {}".format(botocore.__version__))

    print (action + ": " + group)  #Error in this line 
    response = client.update_auto_scaling_group(
        AutoScalingGroupName=group,
        MinSize=min_size,
        MaxSize=max_size,
        DesiredCapacity=desired_capacity,
    )

    print (response)
```